# find session created a job in Oracle

Tags: oracle, plsql

Is there a way from a job running by dbms_schedulet to identify a sid of the session created this job? For instance, session A creates a job B. from B I need to find out sid of A. No params, no passing explicitly via global context, pipe, etc, using only meta data. Thanks

I have checked userenv, dba_schefuler%, v$session views...

Comment: What do you mean by "created this job"? Do you mean the session that created the  scheduler job object, or the session that is *running* the job? Jobs execute autonomously from any client user session. If you want to know who created a job object you should use auditing. `V$` views only show metadata that is true at the *exact* moment you query them; they do not contain historical data. If your job executes quickly, you may never see it in `V$SESSION`. If it takes longer, it should be seen as "ACTIVE" in `V$SESSION`. Any data about the job itself should be captured in the scheduler log tables.

Answer (score -1):

If the job is running synchronously (`dbms_scheduler.run_job`), then the job is running as the session... simply discover it's own SID with `SYS_CONTEXT('USERENV','SID')`

If however it is being run by one the job queue processes (that is, asynchronously, which is normal for scheduler jobs), then there is no association whatever between the job and the session that created it. It would be meaningless to store the SID of a session that is probably non-existent shortly after creating the job. SIDs get reused quickly by other sessions and so are only useful while the session still exists.

You could, at least, audit job creation:

```
audit execute on dbms_scheduler by access;
```

But even so you won't be to tie specific creator SIDs to specific jobs.

Comment: of course it is async. I mentioned that there 2 sessions. Assuming session A is waiting for the end of job B, so both sessions are active on time when checking.

Comment: @Rusty If it is async, then Session A would not be waiting on anything *by definition*. If the job is running in Session B then it has no relationship whatsoever with Session A from the database's perspective.

Comment: I'm afraid you'll have to instrument it yourself. Session A can set its module or action, or register the job id, or many options, but all require you to implement the connection programmatically. When you create a job, there is no relation between the session creator and the job. It isn't like fork() in Unix.. it's more like sticking a row in a table and other processes totally unrelated to you are polling that table looking for things to do. You're basically asking "who originated this row in the scheduler's metadata?" and that isn't something Oracle tracks.

Comment: @Rusty in line with Paul's comment, *auditing* of the create job privilege is how to determine who (which *user*, not which *session*) created a job. In most cases, the creator is also the owner of the job. The job session itself is initiated by Oracle's background processes and never directly by another user session or process.

Comment: @Paul W, you are basically confirmed what I knew, I hoped that there is some data dictionary which I am not aware of... Surprisingly in my app the existing method of generating job names includes SID so all I need to do is to get job name and parse it with regexp... Thanks